# Test with Robolectric and Google Play Service throw me "AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value"

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, robolectric, roboguice

I've an android project which use google-play-services_lib for geolocalization.

I use Eclipse, I imported the library project into your workspace by clicking File > Import, Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace
Then I added the tag

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

as a child of application in my Manifest.xml.

After this, when i run my tests with robolectric, I'm facing with the problem:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  
Expected 4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the 
<application> element: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Consider that I use Roboguice 2.0 and I've the follow order and export:

```
hamncrest-all-1.3
robolectric-2.2
JRE System Library
My_Project
JUnit 4
android.jar
maps.jar
mockito-all-1.9.5
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Good question! Have you found a solution?

Comment: hi Gabriel, looks like my problem is relative to RoboGuice, infact I was injecting a factory that was instantiaiting the "google play service localization". The injection was inside my custom com.google.inject.AbstractModule.